# In Java, why does String == String evaluate to true inside a method (as opposed to using .equals())?

Tags: java, string, equals, equals-operator

If I have:

```
Boolean isEqual = compare("Hello World");

Boolean compare(String c) {
    String s = "Hello World";
    return s == c;
}
```

In my experience, this returns true. Why?

Comment: String literals are "intern"ed which means there is actually only one String.

Answer (score 0):

because its a string literal that has been interned, the same instance is used.

Use `new String("Hello World")` to make it false.

Also asked many many many times before on here

Comment: so why do you answer this and not reffering to the original answer?

Comment: Cool, thanks! Sorry for the duplicate, I'll delete this one. I'm on mobile so I was having a hard time finding someone else who asked this question.